# Extracting Data in different formats in a Text File

Tags: c++, fstream, getline

I'm having an issue with reading in data and I've been researching it for the past hour to no better conclusion. Pasted below are snippets of my code and the file I'm reading form. The file is opened properly and the struct declarations are also shown below as well. I'm confident the solution is simple and that I'm overthinking due to working on this project too long but here's my explanation.

The data file gets opened properly and all the data gets read into the appropiate place until the while(infile>>temp.startDistance.....) part.  My goal at this point is to read in the zombies stated explicitly in each round after the number of random zombies is read( see data file for format). In the previous cases of reading in data, i used getline, than sscanf on the c string version of the string received from getline to extract the appropiate data. Since the explicit zombies are formatted simply with just white space separating the data, I wanted to use the >> operater to extract the data. I've read it's poor practice to mix getline and this but I believe in this case it would make sense. There would be no point in running getline(),strcpy(), and sscanf() which all have O(n) complexity when one 0(n) function (>>) would suffice (This will be tested for speed).

My issue is it reads in the explicit zombies properly in round 1. However, when it reaches the "---" meaning new round so start at beginning of while loop, it exits out of both loops entirely. I've researched flags and thought a failbit would occur and the program counter would go back to the initial while loop to read in a new round. I've tried using peek() to no success and a shortcut that would certainly make me fail some test cases potentially.

I'm just focusing on fixing the final while loop rather than redoing the entire code listed below. If any more information is needed, I'll be glad to add more. Thanks !

```
struct zombiesPerRound{
    unsigned int round;
    unsigned int numZombies;
};


struct zombie{
    unsigned int startDistance;
    unsigned int speed;
    unsigned int health;
    string name;
};

string line;
vector <zombiesPerRound> randomZombies;
list <zombie> masterList;
ifstream infile(inputFile);
if(infile.is_open()){
    //Read in the Player Information
    getline(infile,line);
    char *read=new char[line.length()+1];
    strcpy(read,line.c_str());
    sscanf(read,"Quiver_Capacity: %u",&settings.numArrows);
    delete read;
    getline(infile,line);
    read=new char[line.length()+1];
    strcpy(read,line.c_str());
    sscanf(read,"Random_Seed: %u",&settings.randomSeed);
    srand(settings.randomSeed);
    delete read;
    getline(infile,line);
    read=new char[line.length()+1];
    strcpy(read,line.c_str());
    sscanf(read,"Max_Rand_Distance: %u",&settings.maxDistance);
    delete read;
    getline(infile,line);
    read=new char[line.length()+1];
    strcpy(read,line.c_str());
    sscanf(read,"Max_Rand_Speed: %u",&settings.maxSpeed);
    delete read;
    getline(infile,line);
    read=new char[line.length()+1];
    strcpy(read,line.c_str());
    sscanf(read,"Max_Rand_Health: %u",&settings.zombieHealth);
    delete read;
    getline(infile,line);
    read=new char[line.length()+1];
    strcpy(read,line.c_str());
    sscanf(read,"Player_Health: %u",&settings.playerHealth);
    delete read;
    while(!infile.fail()){
        getline(infile,line);
        if(!line.substr(0,1).compare("-"))
            continue;
        zombiesPerRound randZombie;
        read=new char[line.length()+1];
        strcpy(read,line.c_str());
        sscanf(read,"Round: %u",&randZombie.round);
        delete read;
        getline(infile,line);
        read=new char[line.length()+1];
        strcpy(read,line.c_str());
        sscanf(read,"Num_Zombies: %u",&randZombie.numZombies);
        delete read;
        randomZombies.push_back(randZombie);
        zombie temp;
        //Read in the explicit zombies
        while(infile >> temp.startDistance >> temp.speed >> temp.health >> temp.name){
            masterList.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
}
infile.close();

//test1.txt
Quiver_Capacity: 10
Random_Seed: 2049231
Max_Rand_Distance: 50
Max_Rand_Speed: 60
Max_Rand_Health: 1
Player_Health: 10
---
Round: 1
Num_Zombies: 25
150 300 15 FoxMcCloud
2 3 6 FalcoLombardi
100 1 100 SlippyToad
---
Round: 3
Num_Zombies: 50
20 10 20 DarkLink
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that reading in two different ways (the getline and the >>) does something bad to the input stream (something i don't quite understand to be honest).

I've fixed the problem with this:

```
while(!infile.fail()){
    getline(infile,line);
    if(!line.substr(0,1).compare("-"))
        getline(infile,line);

    zombiesPerRound randZombie;
    read=new char[line.length()+1];
    strcpy(read,line.c_str());
    sscanf(read,"Round: %u",&randZombie.round);
    delete read;
    getline(infile,line);
    read=new char[line.length()+1];
    strcpy(read,line.c_str());
    sscanf(read,"Num_Zombies: %u",&randZombie.numZombies);
    delete read;
    randomZombies.push_back(randZombie);
    zombie temp;
    //Read in the explicit zombies
    while(getline(infile,line)){
        if(!line.substr(0,1).compare("-"))
            break;
        stringstream  ss(line);
        ss >> temp.startDistance >> temp.speed >> temp.health >> temp.name;
        masterList.push_back(temp);
        infile.clear();
    }
}
```

}
infile.close();

I'm pretty sure that there are more elegant / efficient ways to do it, I tested this with the file you posted and it seems to work though.

Hope it helps..